# How to redirect back to preivous template with both input and collections of Eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

I need to pass both input and collections, that this controller produce, to the previous template. I try to use:

```
return redirect()->back->withInput()->with('userdata',$userdata);
```

but get `undefined variable` when access `$userdata` in template.  This is controller:

```
public function inquireUpdateProcess(){
    $input = request()->all();
    $userdata = AuthorityKind::where('authority', $input['authority'])->first(); 
    return redirect()->back->withInput()->with('userdata',$userdata);
}
```

And this is template of view:

```
<label for="text-authority-change">name of authority:</label>
<input type="text" name="authority_name_change" class="form-control"
   value="{{$userdata->authority_name}}" />
```

I use the following instead then it works. But the outcome is couldn't pass the input data and collection in the same time, I know there must be a way to use `return redirect()->back()...` and get both previous input and the collection in template.

```
$userdata = AuthorityKind::where('authority', $input['authority'])->first();
$binding = [
    'title' => 'Authority management',
    'userdata' => $userdata,
];
return view('authority.authView', $binding);
```

Comment: Did you tried to select the data directly from the database, to check if the data exists?

Comment: Yes, the data exists. Otherwise **return view('authority.authView', $binding);** should get nothing and show **undefined variable** , too. But it worked for  **return view('authority.authView', $binding);**

Answer (score 0):

I found out the data put into `with()` can only get it by session in template of blade like this :

```
<input type="text" id="text-authority-change" name="authority_name_change" class="form-control"
  value="{{session()->get('userdata')['authority_name']}}"
  />
```

Even the collections of Eloquent are the the same way to access.